# Creating a fork with the GitHub V3 API (REST)

Tags: api, rest, github, github-api

I'm trying to fork a repo using the GitHub V3 API via REST, however, I am having issues making a POST request as per the docs (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#create-a-fork).

Basically, what I have so far:

- A logged-in user with an OAuth Token
- A POST request setup to the API (URL: `https://api.github.com/repos/carmichaelalonso/infiniteflight/forks/`) - I am testing this with hurl.it to begin with.
- Headers in the request: one has the name `Authorization` with the value 'token ...', the other specifies `Content-Type` with the value `application/json`
- A body with the following JSON: `{"organization" : "shortlisthome"}` (shortlisthome is the account I am trying to fork the repo to.

I am not intending to fork this to an organization, instead of a standard user account, which is where I am getting confused. When I run the request, I do not get any authentication errors or 404 errors (I previously had but I had been entering incorrect values by mistake, causing such errors).

When I run this request though, I get the following result (a 422 unprocessable request):

```
{
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "documentation_url": "---url-to-docs---",
    "errors": [
        {
            "resource": "Fork",
            "code": "invalid",
            "field": "organization"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am unsure whether or not I am able to fork this to a standard user, or if it is an error with my request. Please let me know if I can provide any more info (first post here so a bit unfamiliar with the convention).
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for [shortlisthome](https://github.com/shortlisthome) to fork the repository you need to authenticate as them. The repository you're trying to fork [is public](https://github.com/carmichaelalonso/infiniteflight), so all you need to do is obtain a OAuth token for shortlisthome and then make a similar request to the one you're making now. The only difference will be that you do not need to provide the JSON body of `{"organization": "shortlisthome"}`.

For what it is worth, the optional JSON body is intended for you to use when you are a member of an organization with proper permissions and you want to fork the repository to that organization. You cannot fork a repository to someone else's account unless you are authenticated as them.

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong OAuth key which was why I kept getting an error - thank you very much for clarifying the organisation field (the docs were a little bit lacking on that topic). I will be checking out github3.py and integrating it into my Django project!

Answer (score 0):

I've so far avoided OAuth2, and do not know hurl.  Yet, perhaps this can help.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296984/5411817) shows how it can be done using cURL's `-u` username flag:

`curl -u 'myusername' https://api.github.com/repos/carmichaelalonso/infiniteflight/forks/ -d ''`

The `-d` (or alternatively `--data`) flag turns it into a POST request.
Without that flag cURL defaults to a GET request, which is not what you want.

Since, the data is part of the URI for this request, send an empty string for the data that must follow the `-d` param, as such: `-d ''`.

Of course, using -u will require you to also supply a password..
Here is what GitHub shows using [OAuth2 with their API](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication):

- OAuth2 Token (sent in a header):
  `curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" https://api.github.com`
- OAuth2 Token (sent as a parameter):
  `curl https://api.github.com/?access_token=OAUTH-TOKEN`
- *Read [more about OAuth2](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/). Note that OAuth2 tokens can be acquired programmatically, for applications that are not websites.*
- OAuth2 Key/Secret
  `curl 'https://api.github.com/users/whatever?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy'`

I suspect that adding `-d ''` (or some equivalent in hurl),
plus one of the formats above  for sending OAuth2 info might get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

I used this command to fork on github enterprise
`curl -vX POST https://git.redacted.com/api/v3/repos/<org-to-fork-from>/<repo-to-fork>/forks?access_token=<api-token> -d @gh-fork.json --header "Content-Type: application/json"`

gh-fork.json is just

`{
    "organization": "org-to-fork-to",
    "description": "",
    "homepage": "https://git.redacted.com",
    "private": false
  }`