# Remotely Fork Github Repository

Tags: git, github, git-fork

From my local machine (**Windows 10**) using the command-line, can I fork someone else repository without having to use the **Fork** button on the site?

### Use Case

I'm wanting to create a setup script that forks a repository remotely on Github to a remote Github repository within my account, then `git clone` the forked repository to my local machine.

Comment: "Forking" is not a git feature or function, it's a function of the hosting site. Other than installing a plugin or similar to git locally, git doesn't know how to fork other than the final cloning project.

Comment: You would need to talk to the REST API on GitHub in order to do this, [see this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446157/creating-a-fork-with-the-github-v3-api-rest).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Thank you for this, I think the REST API will be my approach. Load your comment up as an answer re:- REST API.Once Ive built the script i will add it to my question.

DIamond.

Comment: You should look at the "hub" command line tool (https://github.com/github/hub).  There is a fork feature that will let you fork a repo via the REST API.  There are precompiled releases for Windows (https://github.com/github/hub/releases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, "Forking" is not actually a *git* function.

By this I mean that without extra plugins or scripts, git by itself does not have a function "fork", nor does it know how to ask the remote how to do a fork.

Instead, this is purely a function that the hosting partner provides, usually through its web user interface.

However, GitHub have a [REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/), and with it you can instruct GitHub to [manage forks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/).

As such, I think your best way forward would be to either find a script or plugin or program that asks GitHub to do this fork, or build one yourself using this REST API.

Comment: I will say that the documentation for that REST API is lacking at best so I would probably do a search on GitHub itself for projects that use it to find some good examples.

Comment: Yeah im finding that at the moment.