# Forking a GitHub repo using from the command line with bash, cURL, and the GitHub API

Tags: bash, curl, github, fork, github-api

I am having trouble with my bash script to fork a GitHub repo using cUrl.
The gitHub API doc for [creating a fork](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#create-a-fork).

I've tried many variations:

`curl -u $my_user_name https://api.github.com/repos/forks -d "{\"owner\":\"$upstream_repo_username\",\"repo\":\"$upstream_repo_name\"}"`

and
`curl -u $my_user_name https://api.github.com/repos/'$upstream_repo_username'/'$upstream_repo_name'/forks`

yield the following error:

`{
  "message": "Not Found",
"documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}`

In Contrast, the following Creates a new empty github repo, as expected:
`curl -u $my_user_name https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\":\"$upstream_repo_name\"}"`

Any ideas on how to create a fork of a repo from the command line?

I have a bash script that: 
  - creates an empty repo on github with the name of the repo I'm going to clone, 
  - clones a repo from another user locally, and 
  - pushes my cloned repo into the empty repo I created in my github account 
  - sets origin and upstream remotes appropriately

However, this method does not keep a connection within GitHub to the source (forked) repo.  I particularly like the convenience of the forked link appearing below my own repo name ;-)

The goal is to do all my cloning (and forking) from the command line.

I do not want to open a browser, navigate to the repository I wish to fork, just to access that "Fork" button.. only return back to the command line to finish the process.

Alternatively, can I turn a cloned repo into a forked one from the command line? (ie some command line api command that will re-create those internal github links that forks possess?)

Comment: This is much easier done with the `hub` tool from GitHub: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49738033/4752883

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my working bash script:

```
curl -u $my_user_name https://api.github.com/repos/$upstream_repo_username/$upstream_repo_name/forks -d ''
```

Example using hard-coded strings instead of bash variables:

```
curl -u 'SherylHohman' https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/forks -d ''
```

Notice I moved `-d ''` to the end to avoid login errors.
The request requires authentication.
I provide this via curl's `-u` parameter (as opposed to using OAuth2).
When I used the `-u $my_user_name` option,
I had to move the `-d ''` to *after* the URI
- it resulted in login errors if placed between `-u 'username'` and the URI.

**It turns out the Main source of errors in my script with bash-syntax.**
I had quotation marks surrounding bash variables, that should Not have been there.
(..just Solving a pain point without really knowing bash or curl)

Additionally, as #YuriSchimke pointed out, this particular URI required parameters to be passed in the URI.  Passing these options as json is not an option, unlike the URI for Creating a New Blank repo.

Here is why I was baffled over how to send this data in the URI:

Using curl, the [default request is a GET](https://ec.haxx.se/http.html).
In [curl, POST requests](https://ec.haxx.se/http-post.htm) are made by adding the `-d` (equivalent to `--data`) flag followed by the data to be sent.

I needed to send a POST request.
The format for GitHub API is that GET (and POST *eg. CreateRepo*) requests can sometimes [send *some* parameters as json or query strings](https://developer.github.com/v3/#parameters)
NOTE: documentation for GitHub API appears to be slightly incomplete, as I do not see any mention of the API allowing json, only query string.
I suppose in this case, the data is sandwiched between two static URI parts, making it impossible to send as json values.

**I was at a loss how to use the `-d` flag without data**:

If I simply left it off, the API call was processed as a GET.
It returned information *about* the repo I wanted to fork,
instead of *forking* the repo to my account.

[**@YuriSchimke's** post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44279323/5411817) gave me that "Ahaa!".  Thanks! I'm laughing that it didn't cross my mind.  I'm grateful Yuri's made this so obvious! (Thanks Again).

Answer (score 3):

The documentation shows the owner and repo being part of the request URI

```
curl -d '' https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/forks
```

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/

This appears to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

It's much easier to create or fork a repo using the hub command line tool.

Installation instructions: https://github.com/github/hub#installation

It can do much more, but here's how to fork a online repo using the command line.
However, there is conflicting information out there, so it can be a
bit confusing.

**To fork a online repo owned by somebody else do:**

1. clone the repo using `git clone`

`git clone ssh://git@github.com/keras-users/keras.git`

2. change into the cloned repo

`cd keras`

3. create the fork online

`hub fork`

**To fork your own repo that is already hosted on github:**

Github doesn't allow you to fork your own repo,
So you need to first create a clone of your own repo on your computer,
Then you can create the cloned repo on the github website

1. clone your repo to your computer

`git clone ssh://git@github.com/alpha_beta_gamma/clone_repo.git`

2. clone the repo on your computer to another repo (also on your computer)

`git clone clone_repo clone_repo2`

3. change directory to the new cloned repo

`cd clone_repo2`

4. create the cloned repo on Github

`hub create`

This will create a new repo on GitHub.

5. set the URL of the remote repo:

`git remote set-url https://github.com/username/clone_repo2`

6. push the local repo to the online repo

`git push`

Answer (score 0):

I use [hub](https://hub.github.com/).
I have also set `git` as alias for it so that I don't have to worry everytime what command comes under `git` and what under `hub`, so my code looks just like I an running git. Follow installations [here](https://github.com/github/hub#installation).

```
$ git clone <github_repo>
$ cd <github_repo>
$ git fork
```

PS: For the above code to work, before executing it in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` you need to put the following

```
alias git=hub
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this command to fork on github enterprise:

```sh
curl -vX POST \
    https://git.redacted.com/api/v3/repos/$upstream_repo_username/$upstream_repo_name/forks?access_token=$api-token \
    -d @gh-fork.json \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

*gh-fork.json*:

```
{
    "organization": "org-to-fork-to",
    "description": "",
    "homepage": "https://git.redacted.com",
    "private": false
}
```