# How can I fork a github repository using command line only?

Tags: git, github

I want to create a fork of a public github repository using the command line only. How can I do that?

Comment: You'll have to use the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest).

Comment: Use the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_fork) and call `gh repo fork`

Comment: I checked this link already, but does not seem to be a solution

Comment: @chepner API might be a solution

Comment: @Alex It's *the* solution. The CLI is a pre-written wrapper around the API that makes it more convenient to use.

Comment: @chepner The question is "using command line only". I think the `gh` CLI is the solution OP is looking for, since it wraps all the API stuff conveniently into a command I can remember easily.

Comment: That question, [fork using the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274188/forking-a-github-repo-using-from-the-command-line-with-bash-curl-and-the-githu), is a useful reference for how it's implemented, but I would strongly argue that it's not a good duplicate for this question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/)
and run the

```sh
gh repo fork [<repository>] [-- <gitflags>...] [flags]
```

command after getting it setup.